# How to transform using pandas, i.e. removing all the 0 values above 1st non zero value and replacing it with NaN but keeping 0 values if it is after?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

| Date | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | C | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 5 |
| 2022-01-05 | B | 6 |
| 2022-01-06 | B | 7 |
| 2022-01-07 | B | 0 |

| Date | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | NaN |
| 2022-01-02 | B | NaN |
| 2022-01-03 | C | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 5 |
| 2022-01-05 | B | 6 |
| 2022-01-06 | B | 7 |
| 2022-01-07 | B | 0 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to set up a mask:

```
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].where(df['Quantity'].ne(0).cummax())
```

Alternative with [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) and boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['Quantity'].eq(0).cummin(), 'Quantity'] = float('nan')
```

output:

```
         Date Item  Quantity
0  2022-01-01    A       NaN
1  2022-01-02    B       NaN
2  2022-01-03    C       NaN
3  2022-01-04    B       5.0
4  2022-01-05    B       6.0
5  2022-01-06    B       7.0
6  2022-01-07    B       0.0
```